# JPA Query Left Join with A non-declared relation

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I need to query an Entity with a left join with another entity. But I can only declare the ManyToOne relation on the left table:

First table:

```
@Entity
public class ShipyardModel {
   private Long id
   ....etc
}
```

Second table (LEFT one):

```
@Entity
public class Boat{
    private Long id;
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "shipyard_model_id")
    private ShipyardModel shipyardModel;
}
```

Because of serialization reasons I can't declare the @OneToMany relation in the first entity. But they are related, because in the Boat table, i have the `shipyard_mode_id`. So I created a DTO to query this guy for me and created a JPA query:

```
Query(" SELECT new br.com.easymarine.dto.ShipyardModelDTO" +
      "(sm.id, sm.name, sm.commercialLength, sm.length, sm.width, sm.height, sm.beam, sm.weightWithoutMotor, sm.weightWithMotor, sm.modelYear, sm.shipType,s.id, s.name,count(b.id)) " +
      "from ShipyardModel sm " +
      "join sm.shipyard s " +
      "left join Boat b on b.shipyardModel = sm GROUP BY sm.id")
List<ShipyardModelDTO> findAllShipyardModelDTO();
```

The Spring is giving me

> Path expected for join!

error

Is it possible to execute this query the way it is?

Comment: Did you mean to use LEFT OUTER JOIN ON? https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jpa/jpql-left-outer-join-on-condition.html "left join Boat b ON b.shipyardModel = sm"

Comment: I'm sorry, I wrote it wrong here, my code is actually ON b.shipyardModel... And I also tried with left outer join

Comment: I found this query here: `from ShipyardModel sm, Boat b where b.shipyardModel = sm GROUP BY sm.id`
But know I'm having trouble with the left join rule, its executing a right join...